# Accessing interfaces from classes that don't implement them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I have an interface, `IFindable` that is implemented by a few classes.  One other `World` class holds a `List<IFindable> items;`

I have set up a getItems method in my `World` class, to return the list of IFindables.  Now, I am trying to access that list from my `Default.aspx.cs` class (this is a web project).  Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to since this class doesn't understand what IFindable is.  I get the following error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: return type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<IFindable>' is less accessible than
method 'World.getItems()'
```

Why is this?  Have I gone about this wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like your `IFindable` interface isn't public, change it to this

```
public interface IFindable ...
```

If your current declaration looks like this

```
interface IFindable ...
```

Then the compiler is using the default accessibility which is internal

> Interfaces, like classes, can be declared as public or internal types. Unlike classes, interfaces default to internal access. Interface members are always public, and no access modifiers can be applied. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Forgot that C# defaulted to private.  Thanks!

Comment: C# defaults to "the most private available in the context" - which is `internal` for top-level types and `private` for members within a type.

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined your interface as public ?

```
public interface IFindable 
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested making your interface public. An alternative is to make your `getItems()` method internal:

```
internal List<IFindable> getItems()
{
    ...
}
```

(While you're at it, I suggest you either make it `GetItems()` or a property called `Items`, in order to follow .NET conventions. `getItems()` is very Java-like.)

Comment: +1 for not assuming too much about the intentions of the poster.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to put a using statement to the correct namespace at the top of your class file

Comment: No, the compiler clearly knows which type is involved, otherwise it would have complained about that. It can't tell the visibility unless it knows the type.